# load OSX plist to LaunchDaemons with python subprocess

Tags: python, plist, subprocess, launchd

I'm trying to install an OSX LaunchDaemon using python but calling launchctl using subprocess.Popen doesn't actually install the service.

I have the plist file in /Library/LaunchDaemons/ and I can load the plist file just fine using the terminal:

$ **launchctl load -w** /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.myplist.file.plist

$ **launchctl start** com.myplist.file

$ **launchctl list**

"- 0 com.myplist.file"

The service loads and starts properly through the command line, meaning my plist file is correctly set up, But the problem starts when I execute the same commands with python subprocess.Popen or any python system call command.

```
            # Load the service
            command = shlex.split("launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.myplist.file.plist")
            subprocess.Popen(command)
            # Start the service
            command = shlex.split("launchctl start com.myplist.file")
            subprocess.Popen(command)
```

I've also tried setting **shell=True** but no luck. Any thoughts or ideas on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured it out! Thanks for the help, self. Oh, you're welcome, self!

Anyone wanting to install OSX services via python will find this useful.

## Load the service

```
servicePath = '/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.myplist.file.plist'

launchctlCmd = ['/bin/launchctl', 'load', '-w', servicePath]
# Execute service load command
proc = subprocess.Popen(launchctlCmd, shell=False, bufsize=1, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

## Start the service

```
serviceName = 'com.myplist.file'

launchctlCmd = ['/bin/launchctl', 'start', serviceName]
# Execute service start command
proc = subprocess.Popen(launchctlCmd, shell=False, bufsize=-1, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```